# Finding an integrating factor of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Problem:
Solve the following differential equations first finding an integrating factor.
$$ ( 5xy + 4y^2 + 1 ) \, dx + ( x^2 + 2xy  ) \, dy = 0 $$
Answer:
I have no idea how to find an integrating factor. However, the text book from where this problem is found has the following theorem in it.
Theorem:
Consider the differential equation
$$ M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0    \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{(2.42)} $$
if
$$ \frac{1}{N(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{ \partial x} \right] $$
depends upon $x$ only, then
$$ e ^ { \int \frac{1}{N(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x} \right] \, dx } $$
is an integrating factor of Equation (2.42)  If
$$\frac{1}{M(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \right] $$
depends upon $y$ only, then
$$ e ^ { \int \frac{1}{M(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{ \partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \right] \, dy } $$
is an integrating factor of Equation (2.42).
\newline
So, I am going to apply the above theorem.
\newline
\begin{align*}
M(x,y) &= 5xy + 4y^2 + 1  \\
N(x,y) &= x^2 + 2xy \\
M_x &= 5y \\
M_y &= 5x + 8y \\
N_x &= 2x + 2 \\
N_y &= 2y \\
\frac{1}{N(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{ \partial x} \right] &=
 \frac{1}{ x^2 + 2xy } \left[ 5x + 8y - (2x + 2)  \right] \\
\frac{1}{N(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{ \partial x} \right] &=
 \frac{ 3x + 8y - 2}{ 5x + 8y - 2x + 2  } 
\end{align*}
The above expression depends on both $x$ and $y$. Therefore the first part of the theorem does not apply. Now, we try
the second part.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{M(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \right] &= 
\frac{1}{5xy + 4y^2 + 1 } \left[ 2x + 2 - (5x + 8y) \right]  \\
\frac{1}{M(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \right] &=
 \frac{ -3x - 8y + 2}{ 5xy + 4y^2 + 1 }
\end{align*}
Hence the second part of the theorem does not apply. I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$( 5xy + 4y^2 + 1 ) \, dx + ( x^2 + 2xy  ) \, dy = 0$$
Try $\mu (x)=x^3$ :
$$( 5x^4y + 4x^3y^2 + x^3 ) \, dx + ( x^5 + 2x^4y  ) \, dy = 0$$
Regroup some terms:
$$( 5x^4ydx+x^5dy) + (4x^3y^2dx+ 2x^4ydy) + ( x^3dx) = 0$$
$$( ydx^5+x^5dy) + (y^2dx^4+ x^4dy^2) + ( x^3dx) = 0$$
$$d(x^5y) + d(y^2x^4) + ( x^3dx) = 0$$
Integrate:
$$x^5y + x^4y^2 +  \dfrac {x^4}4 = C$$

---

You may ask why I choose $x^3$ as an integrating factor. Start with an integrating factor that only depends on $x$. And we need a power of $x$. So we try $\mu(x)=x^{a}$. We want to make our differential equation exact so:
$$( 5xy + 4y^2 + 1 ) \, dx + ( x^2 + 2xy  ) \, dy = 0$$
$$( 5x^{a+1}y + 4y^2x^a + x^a) \, dx + ( x^{a+2} + 2x^{a+1}y  ) \, dy = 0$$
Our condition for exactness is:
$$\partial_y(5x^{a+1}y + 4y^2x^a+x^a)=\partial_x (x^{a+2} + 2x^{a+1}y )$$
$$5x^{a+1} + 8yx^a=(a+2)x^{a+1} + 2(a+1)x^{a}y $$
We find that $a=3 \implies \mu (x)=x^3$

Comment: Great one! But how did you know that the integrating factor should be a power of $x$? Is that because that's the simplest nontrivial family of functions of $x$?

Comment: You only have power of x and y in the differential equation so ,normaly our integrating factor should be $\mu= x^ay^b$ I tried simplicity. With an integrating  factor that only depends on $x$ and see if I can work it @Allawonder

Answer (score 1):

You had a calculation error: $N_x = 2x + 2y$ not $2x + 2$. So we get
$$
\frac{1}{N(x,y)} \left[ \frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{ \partial x} \right]=\frac{3}{x}.$$
And we arrive at the integrationg factor that user2715281 find.